# Typescript: enum keys as parameter to function

Tags: typescript

I have this enum

```
enum methods {
  DELETE = 1,
  POST,
  PUT,
  GET
}
```

I want to have a function accepting a parameter that can be one of the keys of the `methods` enum.

```
const getMethodPriority = (method /* how do I type this? */) => {
  return methods[method];
};
```

so, for example `getMethodPriority("DELETE")` would return `1`.

How do I type the `method` parameter?

Comment: You can go with `(method: keyof typeof methods)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can directly obtain numbers from numeric enums by converting their values to `number`:

```ts
enum methods {
    DELETE = 1,
    POST = 2,
    PUT = 3,
    GET = 4
}

let enumPriority = methods.DELETE as number;
// enumPriority == 1
```

But if you really want to have a method for this you can:

```ts
enum methods {
    DELETE = 1,
    POST = 2,
    PUT = 3,
    GET = 4
}

const getMethodPriority = (method: keyof typeof methods) => {
    return methods[method];
};

// how to call
getMethodPriority("DELETE");
```

Comment: Sorry!! methodPriorities was supposed to be just `methods`. please see my updated `getMethodPriority` function

Comment: if so - you don't need any function - just convert to number as I wrote in PS section.

Comment: As an added bonus of using the `keyof typeof` combination, you can also do type checking of compound enums, such as a dot-separated path string that gets unpacked later like `'property.subprop.field'` - that's not possible with a direct enum reference.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `keyof` and `typeof` operators like this:

```
enum methods {
  DELETE = 1,
  POST,
  PUT,
  GET
}

const getMethodPriority = (method: keyof typeof methods) => {
    return methods[method];
};
```